# Trigger.io getting gps coordinates

Tags: mobile, gps, trigger.io

I need to find the GPS coordinates of the device running my Trigger app. I need these coordinates to be as accurate as possible. If this were a native app, I would have the option of specifying the location provider (in this case I would specify gps). How do I do this in Trigger? The documentation for geolocation mentions that getCurrentPosition has a parameter for options, but does not explain how to communicate which provider I need.

Comment: As Lord Vader would say "use the forge.geolocation jac... use the forge.geolocation."  Let trigger.io abstract away the details for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition uses assisted gps if it's available.

So it will provide the most accurate location position we can - obviously if the user has manually disabled gps, then it will use less accurate network location.

Comment: Is there any way to check what location provider it is using? Or at least give an error explaining what is preventing the device from using gps (whether the user had disabled gps, or if the device simply couldn't connect)?

Comment: @jac we don't currently provide an API for checking what location provider is in use, but that's something we might expose. Email support@trigger.io with your requirements.